# Generate csv with header and trailer using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where i need to join two flat files and generate a CSV file with a header and trailer using azure data factory.

I have built a dataflow and tried something. I can add a header to the file but the trailer is getting generated into a different file in blob storage. attached the details.

Is there any way to generate with header and trailer? is there a way to escape the double quotes as well?

[dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbzh4.png)
[file1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjG7e.png)

[file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdnHd.png)

Comment: what should be expected output?

Comment: please share the file examples as text in the question rather than screenshot, so we can copy and test. Please Also share an example of the requested output.

Comment: @ChenHirsh I just created a two dummy dataset Employee details and Dept details.

source1:
EMPNO,EMPNAME,SAL,DEPTID
100,John,1000,1
200,Jag,2000,1
300,AL,3000,2
400,Kary,400,2
500,Sean,500,3

source2:
DEPTID,DEPTNAME
1,Finance
2,Operations
3,Data

Expected output as below:
H|EMPNO|DEPTID|EMPNAME|DEPTNAME|SAL
100|1|John|Finance|1000
200|1|Jag|Finance|2000
300|2|AL|Operations|3000
400|2|Kary|Operations|400
500|3|Sean|Data|500
T|6900|5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your file names format, your target files are generating as two files in blob storage. To avoid this and to get a single target file, you need to set the sink configurations like below.

Go to sink **Settings** -> select **Output to single file** and give the file name that you want.

[image]

Set the partitioning to **Single** in the Optimize.

[image]

Now, it will generate all of your data in a single target file.

[image]

And coming to the double quotes, first check whether your data itself has the `""` in the source data preview. If it's not make sure you set the following configurations for the source and sink files.

**Source file:**

[image]

In sink, as we are giving the filename in the dataflow sink itself, here filename is not necessary.

[image]

Set the Column delimiter as per your data.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your help here. However, when change it to "Output to single file", it says "This configuration make your data flow execution longer. The recommended setting is use current partitioning". will it cause any problems if the data grows?

Comment: Source data does not contain quotes. I tried as per your recommendation but still comes as below.

"H|EMPNO|DEPTID|EMPNAME|DEPTNAME|SAL"
"100|1|John|Finance|1000"
"200|1|Jag|Finance|2000"
"300|2|AL|Operations|3000"
"400|2|Kary|Operations|400"
"500|3|Sean|Data|500"
"T|6900|5"

Comment: ok provide your source and sink dataset configurations and data preview of the sink transformation.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. I will provide the config shortly. Can you throw some insights on this please

when change it to "Output to single file", it says "This configuration make your data flow execution longer. The recommended setting is use current partitioning". will it cause any problems if the data grows?

Comment: Yes, the performance will be affected slightly. Normally dataflow will divide the source data and give files based on partition size, but if you want the output to be in single file, that's the only option in this.

Comment: Awesome thanks Rakesh